# How to retrieve angularjs cachefactory.get values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cachefactory

I am storing data to $cacheFactory as such:

```
  $scope.loginCache = $cacheFactory.get('login') || $cacheFactory('login') ;
  $scope.loginCache.put("smsData",$scope.smsData) ;
```

And later am retrieving it with:

```
  $scope.loginCache = $cacheFactory.get('login') || $cacheFactory('login') ;
  $scope.smsData = $scope.loginCache.get('smsData') ;
```

However, I am unable to access the various elements of `$scope.smsData`.  Out putting it to console.log does show all the values there but for some reason I am unable to access the data - what am I doing wrong?

```
console.log($scope.smsData) ;  // displays full object
console.log($scope.smsData.value) ;  // `undefined`
console.log($scope.smsData[0]) ;  // `undefined`
console.log($scope.smsData.value[0]) ; // `undefined`
```

console.log($scope.smsData) outputs:

```
Promise {$$state: {…}}
   $$state:
      status:1
      value:Array(2)
         0:{table: "smsSent", data: {…}}
         1:{apiStatus: true}
```

Ultimately, I am trying to retrieve: value[0].data

Comment: Looks like you are dealing with asynchronous callbacks. Try to resolve it like a Promise: `$scope.smsData.then(function(res){console.log(res.value)})`

Comment: Yup, that was it.  it was saving the promise versus just saving the results of the promise.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `$scope.smsData` is promise object and not a JSON object. What you can do is:

while storing:

```
$scope.loginCache = $cacheFactory.get('login') || $cacheFactory('login') ;
// first resolve the promise and then store in cache
$scope.smsData.then(function(response){
     $scope.loginCache.put("smsData",response) ;
});
```

so, when you will retrieve the data from this `$cacheFactory`, you will get your desired object.